# Alter Bootstrap nav tabs row wrapping

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 3, rows of nav-tabs wrap in a way where the widest rows tend to be at the top while the shorter rows are at the bottom:

[image]

This leaves the tabs looking awkward and unbalanced. Is there a way that nav-tabs can be modified so that the rows are wider at the bottom? More like this:

[image]

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tu6a2yh/) that produced the first image.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo Bar 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBarBaz 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBarBaz 14</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance of an image that shows exactly what you want?

Comment: @Tigger I just posted an image showing what I'm after - wider rows at the bottom.

Comment: Think that using tabs in this case is terrible. Why not a simple buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's not the best solution from the performance point of view but, anyway...Hope, this will be helpful. This solution doesn't depends on specific tab width and provides the result you want.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpxd8eh0/6/

[image: For bigger screen size]

[image: For smaller screen size]

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#sync-tabs');

  updateTabs($container);
  $(window).resize(function(){
     updateTabs($container);
  });

  function updateTabs($tabsContainer){
    var $containerWidth = $tabsContainer.width();
    var tabWidths = [];
    var $tabs = $tabsContainer.find('li');
    $tabs.each(function(index, tab){
        tabWidths.push($(tab).width());
    });

    var formattedTabs = [];
    var maxWidth = $containerWidth;
    var maxWidthSet = false;
    var rowWidth = 0;
    for(var i = tabWidths.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        var tabWidth = tabWidths[i];
        if(rowWidth + tabWidth > maxWidth){
            if(!maxWidthSet){
              maxWidth = rowWidth;
              maxWidthSet = true;
            }
            rowWidth = tabWidth;
            formattedTabs.unshift($('<div class="spacer"></div>'));
        }else{
           rowWidth += tabWidth;
        }
        formattedTabs.unshift($tabs.get(i));
      }

      var $tempContainer = $('<div></div>');
      formattedTabs.forEach(function(tab, index){
        $tempContainer.append(tab);
      });
      $tabsContainer.html($tempContainer.html());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works pretty good as well as the answer I chose.

Comment: I understand your point, but I see some advantages of using this approach: 1) It doesn't contain any "magic" numbers - you can use it with any number of tabs (dynamically); 2) It provides the closest solution to what you described -> you can't get the row that is wider than the last row, event for small screen sizes;
But, of course, it's up to you what approach to chose :)

Comment: One possible bug I found was when I resize the JSFiddle window to make it smaller (on my screen), the tabs will briefly go from 3 rows to 2 rows then back to 3 rows, very quickly. Have you seen this?

Comment: Unfortunately can't reproduce this issue on my laptop. Can you measure on what screen size this issue is reproduced for you? And what browser do you use?

Comment: When I shrink that right frame on JSFiddle down to 766px wide the tabs change from 3 rows to 2 and then at around 755px they change back to 3 rows. This happens in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Here's a little screen capture clip of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy9qycynezl9rgm/screen%20resize.mov?dl=0

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. I can just suppose that it happens due to the top "container" class. I've changed it to "container-fluid" so it takes 100% of screen width. Can you check it now? 
https://jsfiddle.net/cpxd8eh0/7/

Comment: container-fluid gives a similar result - things just change at different sizes. I think it has to do with the column changing as the frame is resized. Using col-md or col-lg gives slightly different behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I have updated the answer with a new and improved solution. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ParaBolt/uary1x6e/). `_.debounce` is a function from Lodash which is being used to improve performance of the resize watcher.

```js
function setTabs() {
  let availableWidth = $('#nav-bar').outerWidth();
  let liNodes = $('#nav-bar li');
  liNodes.removeClass('clear');
  let filledWidth = 0;
  for (var i=liNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    let currentWidth = $(liNodes[i]).outerWidth();

    if (filledWidth + currentWidth <= availableWidth)
      filledWidth += currentWidth;

    else {
      $(liNodes[i+1]).addClass('clear');
      availableWidth = filledWidth;
      filledWidth = currentWidth;
    }
  }
}

setTabs();
$(window).resize(_.debounce(setTabs, 200));
```

Comment: This is close - the tabs line up with the wider rows at the bottom, which is what I want, but they're all in reverse order which doesn't work. Ideally I'd like them to stack with the widest row at the bottom, but be in their normal order.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do something like shown in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxsgdex1/)

You can explicitly use css clear trick to achieve what you want.

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sync-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo Bar 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 4</a></li>
        <li class="clear"><a href="#">FooBar 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 9</a></li>
        <li class="clear"><a href="#">FooBar 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 14</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Binod - That works only works if the column is a fixed size. Once it is resized, things get messed up like: http://i.imgur.com/1cYCljT.png

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that i have done according to your requirements

[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/jobins/wLq30foc/)

```
.nav-tabs
{
  display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
   flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
   align-items: flex-start;
}




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sync-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo Bar 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBar 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBarBaz 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FooBarBaz 14</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE LINK AS PER THE IMAGE GIVEN](https://jsfiddle.net/jobins/wLq30foc/1/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: In this Fiddle there's just one column of tabs. I still want the rows of tabs to be col-sm-6 side, but with the widest rows at the bottom.

Comment: It looks basically the same as the original image. Nothing appears to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what exactly you are looking for, and added following css to look good https://jsfiddle.net/2tu6a2yh/2/

```
.nav-tabs {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width : 100%;
}

.nav-tabs li {
display: table-cell;
width:120px; // constant width
}
```

Comment: Basically I'm looking for the widest rows to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the column sizes for each list item for a more consistent look. Otherwise positions are determined according to the text length they contain. I think, if you make a few trial you'll find the combination you want for each screen size. Try something like following approach

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sync-tabs">
    <li class="active col-sm-4"><a href="#">Foo Bar 1</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">FooBar 2</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">FooBar 3</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">FooBar 4</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">FooBar 5</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-4"><a href="#">FooBar 6</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 7</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 8</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 9</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 10</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 11</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBar 12</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBarBaz 13</a></li>
    <li class="col-sm-3"><a href="#">FooBarBaz 14</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that screen size is fluid - as the browser window is resized, the tabs will move rows.